# How to split text depending on word count

Tags: node.js, split, discord.js

I am trying to make a lyric project using `discord.js`, `cheerio` and the website called `genius.com`.
I have successfully found a way to scrape the lyrics from the website, I am onto the part where I need to split it because discord has a max word limit of 2000.
I can check how many characters/words are in the overall lyrics by doing `lyrics.length`, I just need to find a way to split the string and send both, in the future I might implement `richEmbeds` to make it more stylish but for now I'm focusing on the basics.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

/*
This is a project for my discord bot, the reason for the 2000 word limit is because 
discords character limit is currently set to 2000, this means that i will have to add
a function to split the lyrics and send each part
*/

//Define the URL that we are going to be scraping the data from
var UR_L = "https://genius.com/Josh-a-and-jake-hill-not-afraid-of-dying-lyrics";

//send a request to the website and return the contents of the website
request(UR_L, function(err, resp, body) {
  //load the website using cheerio
  $ = cheerio.load(body);

  //define lyrics as the selector to text form
  var lyrics = $('p').text();

  if (lyrics.length > "2000" && lyrics.length < "4000") {

  } else if (lyrics.length > "4000" && lyrics.length < "6000") {

  } else {
    //send the lyrics as one message
  }
})
```

You can find a live version running [here](https://repl.it/@goodguyben/ShowyNewEngineer) on repl.it.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and use the preview pane to verify, that your code is well indented. If you expect help from us, we expect some effort from you.

Comment: I did put effort into this post I took my time and placed everything including the code block html references as far as indentation goes it looks normal to me so don’t come to this thread to complain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use any fancy function, that function is already built in discord.js: you can attach some options to a message, and `MessageOptions.split` is what you're searching for. When you want to send the text, do it like this:

```
channel.send(lyrics, { split: true });
```

If `lyrics.length` is greater that the limit, discord.js will cut your messages and send them one after the other, making it seem like it's only one.
`channel` is the [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel) you want to send the messages to.

Answer (score 1):

[Discord has a 2000 characters limit](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) not a 2000 words limit.

One solution to your problem could be this:

```
// This will result in an array with strings of max 2000 length
const lyricsArr = lyrics.match(/.{1,2000}/g);  

lyricsArr.forEach(chunk => sendMessage(chunk))
```

Given the async nature of sending messages, you might want to look into modules like [p-iteration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-iteration) to ensure the chunks arrive in the correct order.

That being said, there exists APIs for getting lyrics of songs, which I would recommend instead of scraping. See [apiseeds](https://apiseeds.com/documentation/lyrics) lyrics API as an example.

**UPDATE**

```
    const lyrics = 'These are my lyrics';

    const lyricsArr = lyrics.match(/.{1,8}/g); 

    console.log(lyricsArr); // [ 'These ar', 'e my lyr', 'ics' ]

    lyricsArr.forEach((chunk, i) => {
      // Break if this is the last chunk.
      if (i == lyricsArr.length -1) {
        return;
      }
      // If last character is not a space, we split a word in two.
      // Add additional non-wordbreaking symbols between the slashes (in the regex) if needed.
      if (!chunk[chunk.length - 1].match(/[ ,.!]/)) {
        const lastWord = chunk.match(/\s([^ .]+)$/)
        lyricsArr[i + 1] = lastWord[1] + lyricsArr[i + 1];
        lyricsArr[i] = lyricsArr[i].split(/\s[^ .]*$/)[0];
      }
    })

    console.log(lyricsArr) // [ 'These', 'are my', 'lyrics' ]
```

Updated as per the comments.
This is some crude code that i did not spend much time on, but it does the job.

Some info when using this approach:

- You need to add any symbols that should not be considered wordbreaking to the regex in the second if
- **This has not been tested thoroughly, so use at your own risk.**
- It will definitely break if you have a word in the lyrics longer than the chunk size. Since this is around 2000, I imagine it will not be problem.
- This will no longer ensure that the chunk length is below the limit, so **change the limit to around 1900** to be safe

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation I will try this once my break is over and will post the results as a comment

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I found issue in some case, solved just by editing: `const lastWord = chunk.match(/\s([^ .]+)$/) ?? [];` to avoid null error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split( )` Javascript function.

```
word_list = lyrics.split(" ")
```

And `word_list.length` to access the number of words in your message and `word_list[0]` to select the first word for instance.

Comment: I tried to do that but when I check how many words are in “word_list” by doing “words_list.length” it only shows about 200 which doesn’t make sense to me

Comment: Try to see your text with `console.log(lyrics);`, maybe there is a problem of format and spaces are replaced by other thing or convert it into string with `String(lyrics)`

Comment: Even though if I was to do lyrics.length just after I defined it I get a result of 1000+

Comment: I will try this once I’m back in class at 1 I will post my results then

Comment: i added `console.log(String(lyrics))` under where i defined lyrics and when i ran the code it outuptted the lyrics of the song

Comment: im not sure i have tried it but whenever i log to the console word_list.length it returns with the value 206

Comment: this is what i get when i log to the console word_list:   'life',
  'up',
  'Imma', and for some text it includes the \n within the words